# Naming collision when using MySQL subquery that has a join

Tags: mysql, sql, join, subquery

I'm using a subquery to filter a table, but it joins another table whose values I need as well:

```
SELECT * FROM properties
JOIN (
  SELECT persons.*, cities.* FROM persons
  JOIN properties.* ON properties.person_id = persons.id
    AND (properties.value = 1 OR properties.value = 2)
  JOIN cities ON cities.id = persons.city_id
  GROUP BY persons.id
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT properties.id) = 2
) filtered_persons ON filtered_persons.id = properties.person_id
```

This clashes due to `persons.id` and `cities.id` when naming the subquery `filtered_persons`. The subquery actually comes from a function call in PHP code, otherwise I would simply join `cities` later.

The result is a list of all properties of those persons that have a specific set of properties set.

The resulting query should have `properties.*`, `persons.*` and `cities.*` since it will later be used to further filter it down.

How can I avoid the naming collision without changing the subquery? Is it possible at all?

Comment: You should not be using `select *` with `group by`, so something is seriously wrong with the logic of your query.

Comment: It appears that `filtered_persons.id` is ambiguous because it could come from persons or cities.  You have to resolve this.

Comment: Expanding on what @GordonLinoff said; Using `SELECT persons.*` with `GROUP BY persons.id` should be fine.  It sometimes gives me the shivers, but that is explicitly supported by MySQL - provided that `persons.id` is a unique identifier.  Problems arise, however, when you're also adding `cities.*` to that `SELECT`; If the persons record is associated to multiple cities, you'll only get one city returned.  But the one you get will be completely arbitrary.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create alias and according alias you can set conditions. like 
SELECT * FROM users as userTable INNER JOIN clients as client ON userTable.id=clients.id;

Answer (score 0):

Your code will work fine you should use aliases for cities, persons table.
Since your (id) columns are ambiguous. The columns persons.id and cities.id have same column name for id. There are two tables persons and cities table which have same name column of id. Hence use an alias for column name to get the value.

```
    SELECT * FROM properties
JOIN (
  SELECT p.id as personid , c.id as id FROM persons as p
  JOIN properties as properties ON properties.person_id = p.id
    AND (properties.value = 1 OR properties.value = 2)
  JOIN cities as c ON c.id = p.city_id
  GROUP BY p.id
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT properties.id) = 2
) filtered_persons ON filtered_persons.id = properties.person_id
```